# How to use intids?

Tags: plone, archetypes, dexterity

Looks like intid support has landed to Plone (with Dexterity?)

However there is little information how intids behave or how they should be used (when to use, getting id, look-up by id, when to set id manually) and what packages are involved.

Are there any, even short, instructions regarding this matter?

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.intid

Answer (score 2):

Intid support won't land in Plone any time soon, I think it is optional in Dexterity 1.1 and certainly will be in Dexterity 2.0 which is the version PLIP'ed for Plone 4.3. Just use the plone.uuid support instead (the broken-out Archetypes UID functionality) which is a dependency for Dexterity 1.1 and up.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Still now answer *how* to use it though :)